# python: index of list1 equal to index of list2

Tags: python, list, input, indexing, output

I have 2 lists , they are the same length and in correct order, what i need(i think) is that index of list1 is equal to index of list2 and print the list2 content at that index.

this is what i have so far:

```
id = [10610, 12772, 10611, 13434, 13397, 13854]

name = ['sarah', 'john', 'mark', 'james', 'jack']

userid = int(input('enter user ID: '))
ind = id.index(userid)
 
if userid in id:
    print(ind)
else:
    print('wrong ID')
```

output:

```
enter user ID: 13434
3
```

what i want it to do is, to print the content thats at the same index in "name" list, in this case its "james"

thanks

Comment: `print(name[ind])`

Comment: So why don't you use `ind` to access the corresponding name in `name`?

Comment: @MohitC thank you so much, didnt think it would be this easy, it would be nice if some if anyone has the time to explain how does this work

Comment: @mkrieger1 cause im new, i dont really know what im doing here :D

Comment: @Nightwish highly recommend you to go through some basic tutorials of python programming first before trying anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what the comments said and change it like the following too :

```
    id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    name = ['sarah', 'john', 'mark', 'james', 'jack']

    userid = int(input('enter user ID: '))

    if userid in id:
        ind = id.index(userid) #notice this statement is inside the if and not outside
        print(name[ind])
    else:
        print("wrong id")
```

if you try to use inden(..) before checking if the userid (the one they entered) is in the id , then you will get `ValueError: <some-numer> is not in list`

so its better to do it inside the if

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is do the following:

```
id = [10610, 12772, 10611, 13434, 13397, 13854]

name = ['sarah', 'john', 'mark', 'james', 'jack']

userid = int(input('enter user ID: '))
ind = id.index(userid)
if userid in id:
    print(name[ind])  # Change in this line
else:
    print('wrong ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to print the string from `name` at the same index, you can use `name[ind]`.

Though, there are some other issues with the code given above -

- The if-else condition isn't doing anything. `ind = id.index(userid)` would give a `ValueError` if `userid` isn't present in the `id` list, and the program would crash. This can be refactored to the following:

```py
id = [10610, 12772, 10611, 13434, 13397, 13854]

name = ['sarah', 'john', 'mark', 'james', 'jack']

userid = int(input('enter user ID: '))
 
if userid in id:
    print(name[id.index(userid)])
else:
    print('wrong ID')
```

- The no of elements in `id` and in `name` isn't the same. This can lead to an `IndexError` when the input is 13854. This can be resolved by checking if `len(name) < ind`
- Using two lists isn't a very clean approach. Any manipulation of either array can potentially change the mapping of data. A better approach would be to use a dictionary.

```py
users = {
    "10610": "sarah",
    "12772": "john",
    "10611": "mark",
    "13434": "james",
    "13397": "jack",
    "13854": None
}

userid = input('enter user ID: ')
print(users.get(userid, "Wrong User ID"))
```